# Access multiple variables in class array, across 2 scripts

Tags: c#, arrays, class, variables, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts. Script A contains an array of a Class. The class contains two variables, an int and a string. Script B contains the majority of the code I am executing and needs to access the variables from the Class array in Script A.

(Basically I am trying to make a procedurally generated Tile Map using a mesh. On the first pass I make the mesh. On a second mesh I would like to make the tiles, using a tile Class, that can old values related to the tile,[its name, graphic, attributes, etc.] I would then theoretically do a third pass that would make the textures, thus needing to access the graphic information contained within each tile.)

My problem is that no matter what way I try and do it, I can't seem to get Script B to recognize the array in script A as initialized.  Instead I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the line in which I try and access the variable.

I have tried to do this every way I can think of, even using Lists but couldn't get that to work. I am admittedly new to both C# and Unity. I would like to know why what I am doing is wrong and how to fix it to better understand the process.

Any help that could be provided would be appreciated. The relevant sections of my code is below:

Script A

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TileData {


[System.Serializable]
public class Tile                                                                   
{
    public int tileGraphic = 0;
    public string tileName =     "Unknown";
}



public Tile[] tileArray = new Tile[3]; 

public void makeArray()
{
    tileArray[0] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 0, tileName = "Grassland" };
    tileArray[1] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 1, tileName = "Water" };
    tileArray[2] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 2, tileName = "Forest" };
    tileArray[3] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 3, tileName = "Mountain" };
}
```

Script B

```
 public void BuildMap()                                                                      
{
    //There's other stuff above here that works, I have omitted it for brevity. 
    BuildTiles();
}

public TileData tileTypes;                                                        

void BuildTiles()
{
    Debug.Log("Test Tile Graphic = " + tileTypes.tileArray[0]);
    //Debug.Log("Test Tile Graphic = " + tileTypes.tileArray[0].tileGraphic);
 }
```

**As promised, the entirety of both scrips below. I omitted comments as well as commented out attempts to keep things readable.Thank you all for your help.

SCRIPT A

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteInEditMode] 

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]                                        
 [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
 [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

 public class missionMap : MonoBehaviour {

 public int sizeX = 25;                                                                      
public int sizeZ = 25;                                                                      

public float tileSize = 1.0f;                                                               

public Texture2D testTile;                                                                  
public int tileResolution;                                                                  

void Start ()
{
         BuildMap();                                                                      
    //public TileData tileTypes = new TileData();
}


//Build the Map

public void BuildMap()                                                                      
{
    int numTiles = sizeX * sizeZ;                                                           
    int numTris = numTiles * 2;                                                             

    int vertSizeX = sizeX + 1;                                                              
    int vertSizeZ = sizeZ + 1;                                                              
    int numVerts = vertSizeX * vertSizeZ;                                                   

    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[numVerts];                                             
    Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[numVerts];                                              
    Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[numVerts];                                                   

    int[] triangles = new int[numTris * 3];                                                  

    int x, z;                                                                               //Loop counters.

    for (z = 0; z < vertSizeZ; z++)                                                          
    {
        for (x = 0; x < vertSizeX; x++)
        {
            vertices[z * vertSizeX + x] = new Vector3(x * tileSize, 0, z * tileSize);       //Fills the vertices array with new vector 3's.
            normals[z * vertSizeX + x] = Vector3.up;                                        
            uv[z * vertSizeX + x] = new Vector2((float)x / sizeX, (float)z / sizeZ);        
        }
    }

    for (z = 0; z < sizeZ; z++)                                                             
    {
        for (x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            int squareIndex = z * sizeX + x;                                                
            int triOffset = squareIndex * 6;                                                //We can offset it by 6 (number of verts in a tile [2 traingles * 3 points each])


            triangles[triOffset + 0] = z * vertSizeX + x + 0;                               [NW corner of the square]
            triangles[triOffset + 1] = z * vertSizeX + x + vertSizeX + 0;                   
            triangles[triOffset + 2] = z * vertSizeX + x + vertSizeX + 1;                   

            triangles[triOffset + 3] = z * vertSizeX + x + 0;                               
            triangles[triOffset + 4] = z * vertSizeX + x + vertSizeX + 1;                   
            triangles[triOffset + 5] = z * vertSizeX + x + 1;                               
        }
    }

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();                                                                 
    mesh.vertices = vertices;                                                               
    mesh.triangles = triangles;                                                             
    mesh.normals = normals;                                                                 
    mesh.uv = uv;                                                                           


    MeshFilter meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();                                     
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();                               
    MeshCollider meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();                               

    meshFilter.mesh = mesh;                                                                 
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;                                                         

    BuildTiles();

}



//Build the Tiles

public TileData tileTypes = new TileData();                                                        

void BuildTiles()
{

    Debug.Log("Test Tile Graphic = " + tileTypes.tileArray[0].tileGraphic);



    int[,] tilePosition;                                                                                            

    tilePosition = new int[sizeX, sizeZ];                                           

    for (int z = 0; z < sizeZ; z++)                                                 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {
            tilePosition[x, z] = 0;                                                 
            //Debug.Log("Tile Position: " + x + "," + z);
```

SCRIPT B

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public class TileData {


[System.Serializable]
public class Tile                                                                   
{
    public int tileGraphic = 0;
    public string tileName = "Unknown";
}



public Tile[] tileArray = new Tile[4];                    

public void makeArray()
{
    //for (int i = 0; 1 < tileArray.Length; i++)

    //tileArray = new Tile[3];

    tileArray[0] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 0, tileName = "Grassland" };
    tileArray[1] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 1, tileName = "Water" };
    tileArray[2] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 2, tileName = "Forest" };
    tileArray[3] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 3, tileName = "Mountain" };
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are never creating an instance of TileData: ie public TileData tileTypes = new TileData();

Comment: The above, but initialize `tileTypes` inside a function, not directly when declaring the field. I guess your ScriptB inherits from MonoBehaviour, so `Awake` or `Start` or some other custom intialization function has to do that.

Comment: I tried  TileData tileTypes = new TileData(); as jjhavokk suggested (which I thought I had before) but this leaves the same error. I then tried gunnar b suggestion, however attempting to put it in start,  awake or another function broke the code that came after, even when I had all my braces, etc correct.

Comment: Please post the entire script then.

Comment: @Magnus22191 found the problem. Was able to replicate it with your new code. Please look at the Edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot the problem in your code.

Accessing index that is out of bound.

You have `public Tile[] tileArray = new Tile[3];`

Your index is from 0 to 2. (0,1,2)

But this is what your `makeArray` function looks like:

```
public void makeArray()
{
    tileArray[0] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 0, tileName = "Grassland" };
    tileArray[1] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 1, tileName = "Water" };
    tileArray[2] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 2, tileName = "Forest" };
    ---**tileArray[3] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 3, tileName = "Mountain" };**---
}
```

You accessed `tileArray[3]`? which is out of bound. The highest is 2. This can be solved by either removing that line of code or making your Tile array size 4.  `public Tile[] tileArray = new Tile[4];` Now you can use `tileArray[3]`.

**EDIT**:

With your updated code, your code is still has another in it. You are calling   `Debug.Log("Test Tile Graphic = " + tileTypes.tileArray[0].tileGraphic);` without creating new instance of each `Tile` in the `TileData`. You have a function `makeArray()` that does that but that function is never called.

The fix for this is to call `makeArray()` from `script A` before calling `BuildMap()`.

```
void Start()
{
    tileTypes.makeArray();
    BuildMap();
    //public TileData tileTypes = new TileData();
}
```

OR

You can call it from the `BuildMap();` function instead.

```
 void BuildTiles()
 {
     tileTypes.makeArray();
     Debug.Log("Test Tile Graphic = " + tileTypes.tileArray[0].tileGraphic);
 }
```

You must call it once before accessing the `tileTypes.tileArray[0].tileGraphic.` I suggest you go with the first solution which is calling it from the `Start()` function so that you won't be allocating memory each time you call the the `BuildTiles()` function.

Comment: That's a point too, but his given error message suggest that `tileTypes` is null. He would get an out of bounds exception after that :D

Comment: Didn't fix the problem, but thanks for catching it.  I know better than that,  too. @gunner b. I'll post the code in its entirety one I get home.

Comment: Your edit fixed the problem, thank you. I think I had assumed makearray would work because I was calling in the other script, without realizing that I had never initialized it in the original script. I made the function but didn't call it. Putting it in the start function allowed me to call it and cleared the error.

Comment: @Magnus22191 You had the function but didn't call it. I had to run it to figure that out. Happy coding!